# What are the major Buddhist critiques of Christianity?

Tags: christianity

What are the major Christian teachings that Buddhists don't accept and why? For further reading, can anyone recommend books which critique Christianity from a Buddhist viewpoint?

For context, I am a follower of [Jiddu Krishnamurti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddu_Krishnamurti), whose teachings were similar to Buddha's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Buddhist teachings are three-fold, namely:

1. Morality; non-harming
2. Concentration; unified non-judgmental awareness; unconditional love; unworldly '*heavenly*' states of mind called '*jhana*'.
3. Wisdom of four noble truths; three characteristics; not-self; emptiness of self; natural elements.

Christianity & Buddhism are essentially the same in respect to 1. morality & 2. unified non-judgmental love however different in relation to 3. wisdom.

In fact, it is highly probable the Christian teachings that set Christianity apart from Judaism come from Buddhism & post-Buddhist-Brahmanism (Hinduism). 'Brahma' is the 'Father of All' and the Buddha (in the Tevijja Sutta) taught to non-Buddhist Brahmans that the way or path to Brahma was to radiate limitless unconditional love in all directions, which is essentially the same as what Jesus taught, namely: "*My love is the Way to the Father*" (John 14.6) & "*God is love*" (1 John 4:8).

Buddhism differs from Christianity in that is does not believe in a creator God and believes everything in life, whether physical, mental or Nirvana, is merely natural elements ('dhatu'). Buddhism is strictly impersonal ('*anatta*') where as Christianity believes in personality, including the personality of God.

The following book makes a comparison however I doubt it is completely objective since it seeks to make mutual understanding between religions: [*Christianity & Buddhism - Buddhadasa Indapanno*](http://www.thaicrc.com/gsdl/collect/MIS/index/assoc/D1928.dir/1928.pdf)

Comment: Absolutely.  I think I'd also add that Christianity believes in developing a relationship with that personal God.  It's an important aspect driving most of their theology.  I think it's also what most distinguishes Christian wisdom from Buddhist wisdom.

Comment: Comprehensive. Add some rumours: Jesus in his disappearing years he went to India and became a Buddhist student, returned, with the power to heal and change water to wine; revived the Judaism by incorporating Buddhist teaching into their tribal religion, thus, Christianity.